# how to get seekbar to automatically move on voice recorder?

Tags: android

I have looked everywhere to fix my problem but i just cant seem to get it going.

How do i make seekbar automatically  with voice recorder ?
 I have checked these links but did not find any solution
[Move Seekbar not smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818249/move-seekbar-not-smooth)
[how to get seekbar to automatically move on song play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621336/how-to-get-seekbar-to-automatically-move-on-song-play)

```
lstfile.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    player = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                        player.setDataSource(listFiles[i].toString());

                        player.prepare();
                        player.start();
                        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                                int videoduration=player.getDuration();
                                float progress=i/100.0f;
                                float time=videoduration*progress;
                                player.seekTo((int) time);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler with delay of 500ms or whatever you wish and update the seekbar inside the runnable method.

Refer below code,

```
    Handler seekBarHandler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable updateSeekBarPosRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekPosition();
        }
    };

//UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500ms or reduce/increase it as per your requirement
    private void updateSeekPosition() {
        seekBarHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekBarPosRunnable);
        seekBarMusic.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        seekBarHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarPosRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
    }

Now when you start recording start handler,
        seekBarHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarPosRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
when you stop the recorder remove the callback,
        seekBarHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekBarPosRunnable);
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5466486/sanket-patel Where should I put these codes?

Comment: As i explained in last four line use those code inside your start and end recording methods. Whereas the above code should be written inside the class. Seekbarmusic is your seekbar.

Comment: Seekbarmusic is your seekbar and mediaPlayer is your player. Add start handler inside your onItemClick() method and remove handler callback where you stop playing. No need to write any code in seekbarchangelistener methods.